# How can I convert a single GIF image to a sequence of BMP images with Python

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand, image-conversion

I've been trying to find the best way to convert a given GIF image to a sequence of BMP files using python.
I've found some libraries like Wand and ImageMagic but still haven't found a good example to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

### Reading an animated GIF file using Python Image Processing Library - Pillow

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import GifImagePlugin

imageObject = Image.open("./xmas.gif")

print(imageObject.is_animated)
print(imageObject.n_frames)
```

### Display individual frames from the loaded animated GIF file

```
for frame in range(0,imageObject.n_frames):
    imageObject.seek(frame)
    imageObject.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
from wand.image import Image
with Image(filename="animation.gif") as img:
    img.coalesce()
    img.save(filename="frame%02d.bmp)
```

Use `Image.coalesce()` to rebuild optimized frames, and ImageMagick's "Percent Escapes" format (`%02d`) to write image frame as a separate BMP file.

Answer (score 1):

In Imagemagick, which comes with Linux and can be installed for Windows or Mac OSX,

```
convert image.gif -coalesce image.bmp
```

the results will be image-0.bmp, image-1.bmp ...

Use `convert` for Imagemagick 6 or replace `convert` with `magick` for Imagemagick 7.